# XML produce by RESTful webservice

Tags: java, xml, rest

I have a RESTful web services , up and running and it produces XML output upon a call by the client.

So I have a class to represent the data and I have annotated with @XMLRootElemnt and so it produces the data accordingly as XML. My question is - what is the best way to represent the XML , when there is an inner class in the class that I have annotated with @XMLRootElement? Pardon me if the question is not clear, and if you ask me more detail, I can explain. But if someone already got what I am asking, please advise.

Comment: Could you post an example of the class?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to explain that you want to produce an XML like this:

```
<programmer>
  <name>Marcelo Tataje</name>
  <pl>Java</pl>
  <id>1</id>
</programmer>
```

And you have used something like this to produce it:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Programmer
{
  private String name;
  private String pl;
  private int id;

  public Programmer()
  {
  }
  //here your getters and setters
}
```

And your web services looks like this:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Path("/getProgrammer")
public Programmer getProgrammer()
{
  Programmer p = new Programmer();
  p.setName("Marcelo Tataje");
  p.setPl("Java");
  p.setId(1);
  return p;
}
```

Ant then you invoke your client and so on... I think that's the simpliest way to do it and it's not bad, if you want the best way or a better method it is by using Spring3 which supports Rest and XML, you will have a structure for your requirements in a flash, is a faster framework. Recommended, well I'm answering to you of what I understand to your question.
http://blog.springsource.com/2009/03/08/rest-in-spring-3-mvc/

Comment: Hi Marcelo, Thanks but thats exactly I have currently. But I have to add an inner class in the class - Programmer (say an inner class Tester which has fields - Name and Role.) So now my task is to represent Tester as well inside the XML, so that the output will look like this:                                                                   <programmer>
       <name>Marcelo Tataje</name>
       <pl>Java</pl>                                                  <id>1</id>  
       <Tester> <Name> John Smith</Name><Role> Integration          Test</Role></Tester></programmer>

Answer (score 0):

Got it worked. basically need to use the @XmlElementWrapper and @XmlElement and the field property will be a list of string.